# Changing to a font with spaces in the name using a select option value and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am trying to make a dropdownlist to select a font.

How do I put a space in the option value so Javascript will be able to set the font in style font-family?

HTML:

```
<select id="sltFont" onchange="changeFont(this.valueOf);">
    <option selected disabled>Select a Font</option>
    <option value=”Arial” style="font-family:arial;">Arial</option>
    <option value=”Calibri” style="font-family:Calibri;">Calibri</option>
    <option value=”Candara” style="font-family:Candara;">Candara</option>
    <option value=”ComicSansMS” style="font-family:'Comic Sans MS';">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value=”FranklinGothicMedium” style="font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium';">Franklin Gothic Medium</option>
    <option value=”FrenchScriptMT” style="font-family:'French Script MT';">French Script MT</option>
    <option value=”Impact” style="font-family:Impact;">Impact</option>
    <option value=”JuiceITC” style="font-family:'Juice ITC';">Juice ITC </option>
    <option value=”KristenITC” style="font-family:'Kristen ITC';">Kristen ITC</option>
    <option value=”LucidaHandwriting” style="font-family:'Lucida Handwriting';">Lucida Handwriting</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript Function

Comment: Why can't you just put a space in?

Comment: a space causes the value attribute to lose its end quotation marks.